# Is it idiomatic to say, "What a better place to X?"

Tags: expressions, sentence

Example:

> My first destination was the plant pathology department because—well, what a better
>   place to find out about plants?

Is it common/idiomatic to ask a question with that structure?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The idiom you're looking for is **what better place**, not 'what *a* better place'.  It's commonly used as a comparison with 'than', but that does not preclude it from being used in a case such as yours.

Here's an example:

> [what better place to learn about the forest ecosystem than in a forest](http://www.nps.gov/mabi/blogs/What-better-place-to-learn-about-the-forest-ecosystem-than-in-a-forest.htm)

Comment: Methinks the "than" you mention is even implied in the asker's case, i.e. "...what better place [than that] to find out about plants?"

Answer (score 6):

It should be *What better place [is there] to find out...?*.

?*What a better place* is not the same. I don't believe that phrase actually means anything: if it does, it would be similar to *What a good place...* which is not a question.

Comment: Yes. You seem to be conflating two different idioms. In _what better place_, _what_ functions as a determiner, and the whole phrase is elliptic for something like _What better place could there be). Sentences starting _What a_, on the other hand, are exclamations, not questions, and almost always continue with "adjective" "noun phrase", where the "adjective" is not comparative.